# How to access data in a Postgres hstore field and sum from Active Record

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, hstore

I have a Postgres 9.3.5 DB with a table called order_items. The data is laid out like so.

```
 id | product_sku(character var) | qty_ordered(integer) | item_price(hstore)
1   | 9AYSNL                     | 1                    |"Amount"=>"5.99", "CurrencyCode"=>"USD"
2   | 9AYSNL                     | 1                    |"Amount"=>"5.99", "CurrencyCode"=>"USD"
3   | 9AYSNL                     | 2                    |"Amount"=>"11.98", "CurrencyCode"=>"USD"
4   | 9AYSNL                     | 1                    |"Amount"=>"5.99", "CurrencyCode"=>"USD"
5   | EZAY1D                     | 1                    |"Amount"=>"21.98", "CurrencyCode"=>"USD"
```

What I would like to do is find out how often each product_sku occurs in the table as well as the total "Amount" for that product.

If I run the following I get this result.

```
products =  OrderItem.where('quantity_ordered > 0').group(:product_sku).count

{"9AYSNL"=>4,
"EZAY1D"=>1}
```

I would like to somehow return something like the following (total_orders is the number of times the product_sku is in the table not the qty ordered). I would like to return the top 20 by total_orders.

```
[{product_sku: "9AYSNL", total_orders: 4, total_order_amount: "29.95"},
 {product_sku: "EZAY1D", total_orders: 1, total_order_amount: "21.98"}]
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Postgres is 9.3.5.1
I updated the sample data based on your question. The amount is tied to qty ordered. So where 2 were ordered the Amount is 11.98.

Answer (score 2):

To get the bare result:

```
SELECT product_sku
     , count(*) AS total_orders
     , sum((item_price->'Amount')::numeric) AS total_order_amount
FROM   orderitem
WHERE  qty_ordered > 0
GROUP  BY product_sku
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT  20;  -- get only top 20
```

To get the result as JSON array like you display:

```
SELECT json_agg(t)
FROM  (
   SELECT product_sku
        , count(*) AS total_orders
        , sum((item_price->'Amount')::numeric) AS total_order_amount
   FROM   orderitem
   WHERE  qty_ordered > 0
   GROUP  BY product_sku
   ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
   LIMIT  20
   ) t;
```

[**SQL fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/19c63/1)